# Comparison principle for p-harmonic functions.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, maximum-principle

[image]

The proof begins by considering the open set $D_{\varepsilon} = \{ x \in \Omega : u(x) > v(x) + \varepsilon \}$ for some $\varepsilon > 0. $ Then it says that $D_{\varepsilon} = \emptyset$ or $D_{\epsilon}$ is compactly contained in $\Omega.$ Clearly if  $D_{\epsilon} = \emptyset$ then there is nothing to prove. But how do I show that if $D_{\varepsilon} \neq \emptyset$, then $D_{\varepsilon}$ is compactly contained in $\Omega.$ Am I using the assumption that $\limsup u(x) \leq \liminf v(x)?$

Comment: Pardon my ignorance: What is a $p$-harmonic function?

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @MartinR: It's a solution to the $p$-Laplace equation $\Delta_p u = 0$ (see [$p$-Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-Laplacian) on Wikipedia, or [Notes on the $p$-Laplace equation](https://folk.ntnu.no/lqvist/p-laplace.pdf) by Peter Lindqvist, from which the picture in the question is taken).

Comment: @HansLundmark: Thanks, I did not know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K$ be the closure of $D_\epsilon$. $K$ is compact because it is bounded and closed. If we can show that $K \subset \Omega$ then
$$ 
D_\epsilon \subset K \subset \Omega
$$
so that $D_\epsilon$ is compactly contained in $\Omega$.

We surely have that $K \subset \overline \Omega$. If $K \not\subset \Omega$ then
$$
 K \cap \partial \Omega = \partial D_\epsilon \cap \partial \Omega
$$
is not empty, so that there is a sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n \in D_\epsilon$ which converges to a point $\zeta \in \partial \Omega$. But then
$$
 \limsup_{x \to \zeta} u(x)- \liminf_{x \to \zeta} v(x) 
\ge \limsup_{n \to \infty} u(x_n) - \liminf_{n \to \infty} v(x_n) 
\ge \limsup_{n \to \infty} \bigl(u(x_n) -v(x_n)\bigr)\ge \epsilon
$$
is a contradiction to the given boundary condition.

Note that specific properties of the functions $u$ and $v$ (such as being $p$-harmonic) are not needed for this conclusion, only the boundary condition.

Comment: How do you know that there is a sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n \in D_{\varepsilon}$ which converges to a point $\alpha \in \partial \Omega$?

Comment: @BillyBOB1: If $K$ is not a subset of $\Omega$ then it must intersect the boundary of $\Omega$. And since $K = D_\epsilon \cup \partial D_\epsilon$ and $D_\epsilon \subset \Omega$ it follows that $\partial D_\epsilon \cap \partial \Omega$ is not empty. Now choose $\zeta \in \partial D_\epsilon \cap \partial \Omega$.